# SQL Trigger AFTER INSERT is not following my IF statements and not deleting the new row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I made a trigger that each time I insert into the table 'Invoices' it checks if the quantity (amount ordered) is higher than the amount of stock available from a different table.
If the quantity is higher it should print that there is not enough stock and delete the newly inserted row.
it's not doing that at all. It just inserts the row and no message is printing out.

```
create trigger testtrigger
on invoices
after insert
as
begin
declare @productID int
declare @quantity int
declare @stock int
select @stock = stock from Products where ProductID = @productID
select @productID = productid from inserted;
select @quantity = Quantity from inserted;
if @productID not in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) 
    begin
        if @quantity > @stock
        begin
            Print N'Not enough Stock. Current Stock: ' + @stock
            delete from Invoices where InvoiceID = @@IDENTITY
        end
    end
end
```

the first 6 products are not something with a stock amount, it's a service so I didn't want it to trigger on orders on those product IDs.

this is only part of a bigger If Else that checks more things (such as an else statement to update remaining stock if quantity is less than stock but this is the start of the trigger and it doesn't work so I thought I would start here.

Comment: Your trigger is severely flawed; it *assumes* an `INSERT` only ever contains 1 rows. That is simply not true. Also, normally, you wouldn't `DELETE` the row, and `PRINT` an information message, you would `THROW` an error.

Comment: What should happen if 2 rows are inserted for the same product as well?If the *other* table has the value `20` and both inserted rows have the value `15`, then both are less than `20`, however, you certainly don't have `30` in stock. One would *expect* that the *other* table's (stock?) column should be updated at the same time.

Comment: if i do throw instead of delete will it still remove the inserted row? 
I'm not sure how I would change it to accommodate bulk inserts :/ is there a way to make it read the inserts row by row?

Comment: *"is there a way to make it read the inserts row by row?"* don't do that, triggers should have as **minimal** impact on the DML statement as possible; looping through your inserted data would be *awful* for performance.

Comment: *"if i do throw instead of delete will it still remove the inserted row? "* Assuming you `THROW` an error with a high enough severity and are handling rollbacks automatically, or in your `TRY...CATCH` yes. But what you are asking here results in more questions here; there are several flaws in your idea here.

Comment: but if i need to make sure there is enough stock what should I do it through? i thought that through a trigger I could update the other table automatically for each insert, is there another way?

Comment: _"there are several flaws in your idea here"_ yeah this is part of the first project I was assigned in my SQL  course so I'm sure there's a lot more of that

Comment: *"but if i need to make sure there is enough stock what should I do it through?"* I would, personally, expect that the stock levels of the product would be updated, and there should be a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` on said column to ensure it can't be less than `0`; then a error would be raised by the RDBMS and provided you have your transactions and `TRY...CATCH` properly set up, you can `ROLLBACK` the whole lot.

Comment: You'd also need to likely ensure there is appropriate row locking on the stock table while performing the `INSERT` on the Orders table for a *real world* solution.

Comment: @Cotton how did you get on with the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

For *any* T-SQL, including triggers, you need to get into the mindset of set-based operations, *not* procedural, RBAR (Row By Agonising Row), operations.

Triggers provide you with the [`Inserted` (and for update/delete triggers `Deleted` pseudo tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15) which you should be using as you would any other table i.e. in a set-based fashion.

As pointed out in the comments, triggers need to run as fast as possible because they are holding locks while you do your processing.

```
create trigger testtrigger
on invoices
after insert
as
begin
    set nocount, xact_abort on;

    -- Check if *any* of the inserted products exceeds the current stock levels
    -- Taking into account the possibility of the same product occurring in multiple invoices
    -- You could use similar logic to capture the products for which the stock level was exceeded
    -- However its very complex to only rollback those which are wrong.
    -- Really this should be your last line of defence, only used to ensure database integrity, so you should be checking stock levels before now
    -- And therefore it shouldn't matter rolling everything back
    if exists (

        select 1
        from Inserted I
        inner join Products P on P.ProductId = I.productId
        where productID not in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
        group by P.Id, P.Stock
        having sum(I.Quantity) > P.Stock;

    ) begin
        -- If you want to do something in your calling code you need to throw an exception. Printing is only relevent while testing in SSMS.
        -- Throwing an exception will also roll back the transaction
        throw 51000, 'Not enough Stock.', 0;
    end;

end;
```